# How do I mimic categories or folders in Google Keep?

Tags: google-keep

The note-takers that I use, use folders. 
I'm used to using folders.

How do you mimic folders in Google Keep?

One thing that I thought of is to keep a separate note that has the list of all tags, but it's too much work writing a tag and then putting it in a different note. Clicking in the list of folders is faster.

Comment: Far from ideal but... using folder colors ?

Comment: @danidemi This is close to an answer, but not quite there in terms of detail. Could you expand on it a bit more and edit the changes into your answer?  Then you can flag it to be undeleted.

Answer (score 6):

Keep now supports Labels. you can filter your notes using Labels.

[Organize notes with labels - Google Keep help](https://support.google.com/keep/answer/6191044?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

In Google Keep you can change the color of your notes. So, one idea could be to use a specific color for all notes you would like to move into a folder. Just as an example, you could use "green" for "friends" related notes, "yellow" for "meeting" related notes, and so on. In this way, at first sight, you would know what a note concerns. To change a note color, move the pointer over a note, and then on the palette that will show up in the bottom, then click the color you like.

Comment: You would still need  special note that lists colors and names of folders

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new note, you can use a title that contains a sort of label. For instance, you can use for notes about friends, these titles: "[FRIENDS] Dinner @ Joe", "[FRIENDS] Beer with Jean", "[JOB] Phone back Paul". Then, in the search folder, it's enough to type the label you are interested in. So, if you want to retrieve all the notes labelled as JOB, just search for "[JOB]".

Comment: This the same as having tags in the title

Answer (score 1):

You could create labels as such:

Home
Home/Kitchen
Home/Bedroom
Home/Bathroom

Work
Work/Instructions
Work/Vehicle Maintenance
Work/Contacts

Total list of labels still gets pretty long but since they are in alphabetical order shouldn't be to bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use notes themselves as folders.

Each note has its own URL so you can in theory create a note called my house.

Then create more notes My Kitchen, My Bedroom, My Bathroom, etc...
On the desktop when you open a keep note the URL changes to the direct address.

So when you click on My Kitchen copy the URL
Then open My house and Type something link "My Kitchen -" then paste the URL.
click on My Bedroom copy the URL
Then open My house and Type something link "My Bedroom -" then paste the URL.

The notes are still all in the same place they have always been but now at least your "house" has a folder structure.